# VBA looking up information using criteria that is repeated

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of client ID, which is associated with policy numbers. They are both in columns next to each other. 
The client ID can be associated to multiple pol number for e.g. 
 Col_a Col_b
cl id  pol num
a      1
a      34
a      9
b      4

I am trying to build a macro where if I was to enter client id a on a cell in a different sheet it would give me all possible pol numbers in the column next to it. There are abt 11K of these so can't do them manually.

Any advice?

Comment: Use a PivotTable and a Slicer. And provide more comprehensive sample data in your next question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of code to get you going. It's using the Worksheet_Change event to detect changes to a particular cell (in this case, D5). I would recommend formatting your Client & Policy data as a table so you can easily and dynamically reference it.

This assumes a table named "PolTable" with a column named "Client ID". It will output a string of policy numbers such as 1, 34, 4 when "a" is typed into D5.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Rng As Range
Dim Policies As String
Dim Tbl As ListObject
Set Tbl = Me.Range("PolTable").ListObject

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D5")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        For Each Rng In Tbl.ListColumns("Client ID").DataBodyRange
            If Rng = Target Then
                If Policies = "" Then
                    Policies = Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
                Else
                    Policies = Policies & ", " & Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Policies
    End If
End If

End Sub
```